# What's the maximum amount of RAM Ubuntu

Tags: ram

In my IT classes I learned Windows 32 bit could support at max 4GB of RAM and that got me curious, what's the maximum amount of RAM Ubuntu can currently support if there is a max currently. Already tried looking it up on Google couldn't really find anything.

Comment: 64-bit Linux can support practically any amount of RAM that can be installed. Not less that 128 TB I guess.

Comment: Intel/AMD's 32-bit processors with PAE have no 4GB RAM limitation; Windows XP SP2 was supposed to support >4GB, except they couldn't remove the bugs, so it was pushed to SP3, then SP4 then the >4GB RAM for 32-bit was dropped..   Linux has no such limitation, but I've voted to close this question as being off-topic seeking opinion.  You've not provided any Ubuntu product, and even then it's immaterial as 32-bit machine hardware has limits far smaller than Ubuntu or GNU/Linux does so Ubuntu's limits will never be reached.

Comment: 32-bit is also *vague* as *ppc* was 32-bit (*ppc64el* being the 64-bit version; and *armhf* is the 32-bit version of ARM, so 32-bit of which processor architecture?   Limits can vary on architecture & Ubuntu has supported multiple 32-bit architectures...  (*FYI:  My prior comment related only to x86 or i386 in Debian/Ubuntu terms, ie. i686, as adding other architectures just complicated things as PAE is an intel/AMD or x86 issue only*)

Comment: 32-bit ARM may also be more complex; alas sorry I'm unsure.  I mentioned *armhf* as for what I know Ubuntu supports; but that's also called *armv7* or the ~7th *major* 32-bit architecture of ARM, but note not all ARM 32-bit are compatible with each other; why it's *armhf* (F being the 32-bit version) & not *arm32*... thus ARM being more complex than say *ppc* or *i386* or other Ubuntu supported 32-bit architectures...  Some of those older 32-bit ARM had **smaller** than 32-bit memory addressing...  (word size & memory address size doesn't always match!)